# AdSense disapproved, cannot resubmit

Tags: google-adsense

I submitted an AdSense request that was disapproved. They sent me the usual email, telling me that there isn’t enough content.

I checked the situation with feedthebot, and fixed several issues, including the content issue
(the web site, http://ciudadelas.net/ has been online for several years) so, now it is all OK (or so I think).

But the email tells me to go to http://www.google.com/adsense and resubmit the request. I do, but that URL always gives me:

> Account Not Active
>   An AdSense account does not exist for this login, as it is associated with an unapproved application. For more information about your application, please review the message we sent to the email address you provided with your application"

I have fixes all the issues. They don’t send me more emails. Why can’t I resubmit? Is it a bug?
How can I ask to recheck my request?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple. Your email account and/or the website is linked with another unapproved account. If you want to isolate this issue, create a new blog and add enough content.
When you are done, link it to your gmail and apply for AdSense. If your request is approved, then it means the other website is linked to another account via Webmaster or AdSense.